# Passing Values of Spans to php with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom, dwolla

thanks for taking the time.  I'm working on building a visual shopping cart into multiple pages of a parallax site.  Because each 'page' of the parallax forces open and close a form, I cannot use a continuous form.  To remedy this, I am using jquery to place the value of the choices on the preceding pages into one page, filling spans.

I'd like to be able to grab these final choices from the dom using ajax to put them to a processing page to store the customers choice information, and check it against a dwolla transaction.  I haven't got to setting up the dwolla transaction and check yet, because I have not been able to get my data to the php processing page, and get it to return an echo-able value.  This is built off wordpress by the way, and allot of times, filters wordpress is implementing screw me up.

Here's the site;  http://ecigjuiceclub.com

Lets jump into the code!

AJAX:

```
function post()
{
    var name = $('#cname').val();
    var street1 = $('#cstreet').val();
    var street2 = $('#cstreet2').val();
    var city = $('#ccity').val();
    var state = $('#cstate').val();
    var zip = $('#czip').val();
    var email = $('#cemail').val();
    var phone = $('#cphone').val();
    var flavor = $('#cflavor').val();
    var strength = $('#cstrength').val();
    var refcode = $('#crefcode').val();
    $.post('process.php',{postname:cname,poststreet1:cstreet,poststreet2:cstreet2,postcity:ccity,poststate:cstate,postzip:czip,postemail:cemail,postphone:cphone,postflavor:cflavor,poststrength:cstrength,postref:crefcode},
    function(data)
    {
        $('#thankyou').html(data);
    });
}
```

Php process.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['postname'];
$street1 = $_POST['poststreet1'];
$street2 = $_POST['poststreet2'];
$city = $_POST['postcity'];
$state = $_POST['poststate'];
$zip = $_POST['postzip'];
$email = $_POST['postemail'];
$phone = $_POST['postphone'];
$flavor = $_POST['postflavor'];
$strength = $_POST['poststrength'];
$refcode = $_POST['postref'];

if($zip == 90804)
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
  echo "0";
}
?>
```

HTML Snippet (where in the DOM I'm attempting to grab):

```
<span style="color:#EF5D3D;">Email:  </span><span style="font-size:28px;" id="cemail"></span>
<span style="color:#EF5D3D;">Phone:  </span><span style="font-size:28px;" id="cphone"></span>
```

Comment: You can only use the `.val` method for form control elements. If you want to get the text content of an arbitrary element, use `.text`.

Comment: I had tried using .text as well but I am still getting no response to the page and the debugger looks like it is inserting the 'click' into the recovered field.  Maybe I am just not drilling in? `TypeError: Value does not implement interface HTMLElement.`

Answer (score 0):

i think you better try innerHTML instead values i dont know the exact syntax in jquery. iprefer u use input or else instead span

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = $('#cemail').text();
var phone = $('#cphone').text();
```

These should be the replacements on the post() function. Adding an alert message (as an example) at the opening of the post() function could help you check their values before they get passed in the Ajax request.

```
alert($('#cemail').text() + ' ' $('#cphone').text());
```

Also make sure to clear your cache just to make sure your javascript edits have been implemented.

Comment: Good call on trying to push out on an alert, I had started the post() with an alert check which worked fine.

Comment: I need more rep to be able to upvote you, I am at least seeing that its getting to the ajax correctly using the alert now.

Comment: Probably my own fault. **Please upvote bonbon.langes**, should have kept the alerts going the whole way through.  It was how I structured my ajax array, I was trying to post the div ID names, instead of the new JSON variable names I was creating.  reformatting the script helped me to see that more clearly.  The form is now correctly returning a 1/0 toggle based on the zip code definition, so we're ready!  I haven't found an explanation for grabbing the values of spans, but using .text to grab a span was the answer, again bonbon.langes

Answer (score 0):

The console is showing the following errors which may or maynot prevent other scripts from running:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined
>   ecigjuiceclub.com/:825
>
> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://ecigjuiceclub.com".  The frame requesting
>   access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a
>   protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Comment: Awesome, good catch, I didn't think of clearing that off first, I'm using their js to do the autoplay, i've cleared the error, but still getting the other HTMLELement error on submit.  Thanks you are awesome!